# Qt tablView with model containg pointer to custom class

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, qgraphicsitem

I created my custom class (CustomObject), that inherit from QGraphicsItem. I use those object to draw on scene (rectangles, polygons and stuff) and I store pointers to them in QList. Now I need to display all my CustomOBjects in tableView, but there are 2 conditions:

1. When I select and interact with object in tableview - I must be able to interact with "real" CustomObject represented by it (example: I selected obj1 in tableview and click button "delete" or "edit" - and I want to be able to interact with acctaul object (delet or edit it).
2. When I add new or change it - i wish to see change in tableView.

I'm not sure if i can achieve that with jsut table view and soem custom mdoel - or shoud I make my own QAbstractItemModel class, but if i do - how do i do it? Shoud i make class inherit from QAbstractItemModel and add pointer to my CustomObject, or just force my CustomObjects into soem specific model?

Little bits of my code:

Here is my CustomObject.h
//I removed some code that was stricly related to "personal" functions related with specific features of my app

```
    class CustomObject : public QGraphicsItem
    {
    public:
        CustomObject();
        CustomObject(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h);
        virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;

        void set_Name(QString name);
        QString get_Name();

    protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
        void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

    private:
            QString Name;
```

I store them in list, in my "Overseer" class:

```
    class ObjOverseer 
    public:
            void drawingCustomObject_Do(int x, int y); //This function creates new "CustomObject" and adds it to the list (below)

        QList<CustomObject*> ObjectsList_CustomObjects;
```

In my mainwindow - I simply create that ObjOverseer and keep its pointer.

**EDIT 1**

I used this example:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/itemviews-addressbook.html
and created this class:

```
    CustomModelOfCustomObject::CustomModelOfCustomObject()
    {
    }

    CustomModelOfCustomObject::CustomModelOfCustomObject(QObject *parent)
         : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
     {
     }

    CustomModelOfCustomObject::CustomModelOfCustomObject(QList<CustomObject*> objects, QObject *parent)
         : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
     {
         ListOfObjects=objects;
     }

    int CustomModelOfCustomObject::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        return ListOfObjects.size();
    }

    int CustomModelOfCustomObject::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        return 2;//TODO - ZMIENIC ILOSC KOLUMN
    }

    QVariant CustomModelOfCustomObject::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

        if (index.row() >= ListOfObjects.size() || index.row() < 0)
        return QVariant();

        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        CustomObject* obj = ListOfObjects.at(index.row());

        if (index.column() == 0)
            return obj->get_Name();
        else if (index.column() == 1)
            return obj->get_Address();
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

    QVariant CustomModelOfCustomObject::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
    {
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
            return tr("Name");

            case 1:
            return tr("Address");

            default:
            return QVariant();
        }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

    bool CustomModelOfCustomObject::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(index);
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position+rows-1);

        for (int row=0; row < rows; row++) {
        CustomObject* obj;
        ListOfObjects.insert(position, obj);
        }

        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }

    bool CustomModelOfCustomObject::removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(index);
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position+rows-1);

        for (int row=0; row < rows; ++row) {
        ListOfObjects.removeAt(position);
        }

        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }

    bool CustomModelOfCustomObject::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
    {
        if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
            int row = index.row();

            CustomObject* p = ListOfObjects.value(row);

            if (index.column() == 0)
                    p->set_Name(value.toString());
            else if (index.column() == 1)
                    p->set_Address(value.toString());
        else
            return false;

        ListOfObjects.replace(row, p);
            emit(dataChanged(index, index));

        return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    Qt::ItemFlags CustomModelOfCustomObject::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

        return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }

    QList<CustomObject*> CustomModelOfCustomObject::getList()
    {
        return ListOfObjects;
    }
```

But still, when i reach point in my function where i shoud use this model- i dont know hwo i shoud add it or even if i will be able to use it as intended.

**EDIT 2**
When i chaned ListOfObject to public and tried:

```
   MyModel->ListOfObjects.append(newObj);
```

all crashed

Comment: You can create your own model by inherit from qabstracttablemodel. Please check about http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

Comment: That problem still isn't resolved. (@Edit 1) I tried to implement my own class but stumbled accros antoher problems and i woudl apriecieate some more help with this.

Comment: You can't add data directly to the source of data. If you want to add call MyModel->insertRow(), after you insert then you edit your data manually.
So, if you want to add, delete, move the rows, it should call through model api. If you want to edit you can edit directly to your custom class data and then refresh the model

Comment: Oook, lets say i will make it that way - update model on addition/delete from my list, but how will i be able to "delte" object based on user selection in my tableview (whcich will only have model) - since name and address can't be percived as primary keys.

Comment: Your tableview and the model are connected, so don't worry about it. Every item on the tableview has QModelIndex which represent the row and the column on table view and on your model. If you still confuse, you can make a simple code about this and share it to me by dropbox or anything else, i will try to help you.

Comment: Issue isnt to conenct tableview - model, but model - list.

Comment: And i already created "simple code about this" - it's placed in my question (@ Edit  1) and I'm still confused and have no clue hwo to finally make it work (even create simple display of those 3 columns (id, name, addreess))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Now i only add "representation" of object to model and whenever i need to update any object (ew. change name or color) i just do it via my overseer, passing soem kind of guid/identifier/id/anything that woudl let me tell objects apart form eachother.

Comment: Even I am stuck with the same problem. I need to add custom object data to the tableview and populate it accordingly. I will be having a unique id field in the custom object. Whenever I get a request to delete the id object I need to delete it from the table. Can you help me in providing the source code for this. I am highly confused and I couldn't able to figure out from the past 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is, you list in ObjOverseer and CustomModelOfCustomObject are not connected, you need to save the pointer of ObjOverseer list instead of copy it to CustomModelOfCustomObject. This one :

```
CustomModelOfCustomObject::CustomModelOfCustomObject(QList<CustomObject*> objects, QObject *parent)
     : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
 {
     ListOfObjects=objects;
 }
```

You need to add function to your CustomModel that will handle adding new customobject :

```
 bool CustomModelOfCustomObject::insertNewData(CustomObject  *obj, int rowposition = -1)
{
    int row = rowposition < 0 ? ListOfObjects.size : row;
    beginInserRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
    ListOfObjects.insert(row, obj);
    endInsertRow();
}
```

And when you want to add new object, simply call those function. If you list on model is connected to ObjOverseer (pointer type), you does not need to add new object to your ObjOverseer.